# Save items similar to the key on a map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a map that initially has empty lists as values. And a list with various data. What I want to do is to search the list for items similar to the map keys and add them as values.

This is my code:

```
void main() {
  List list = [];
  var maps= { 
    'A' : [],
    'B' : [],
    'C' : [],
  };

  List y = ['A','B','C','A','B','C'];

  maps.forEach((key,values){
    List temp =[];
    for (var i in y){
      if(key == i) {
      list.add(i);
    } 
    temp = list;
  }
  maps[key] = temp;
  list.clear();
  print(maps);
 });
}
```

This is the result I get

```
{A: [], B: [], C: []}
```

And I need this result

```
{A: [A,A], B: [B,B], C: [C,C]}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How many times print function executed? It should prints three lines, are they all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that at no point are you directly manipulating the existing `List` with the matching key in your `Map`.

And you don't need the `list` or the `temp` variables.

```
var maps = {
   'A': [],
   'B': [],
   'C': [],
  };

  List y = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'];

  maps.forEach((key, value) {
    for (String char in y) {
      if(char == key) {
        maps[key]!.add(char); // this is what adds the matching String from the list to the corresponding list in the map       
     }
    }
   });
log(maps.toString()); //  {A: [A, A], B: [B, B], C: [C, C]}
```